# How to create section header listing like WhatsApp in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

My UI is like chat application

[image]

My chat message will be on left side only for both `sender` or `receiver` .But I'm stuck at how to group messages according to it's date and when we scroll it down,Date indicator stick at the top position just like WhatsApp.As per screenshot i have taken both Label for date and message text inside cell But i want first message of the day will display like time, date and then message related to particular day and so on ... How can i achieve that? Also i want to show delete option when i hold cell like WhatsApp.

Comment: you can [headerView(forSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614965-headerview) To show time. And Use UIGestureRecognizer to detect long press.

Comment: could u tell me @LalKrishna